# Documentation Beta Badge

Tags: discussion, badges, documentation

Was there any mention of needing to have three "substantive pieces of documentation" for the Doc Beta Badge *before* the private beta ended? The only info I saw was the email I received that said (in part):

> *a little birdy told me there might be a new badge for private beta participants coming too, which can still be earned by contributing between now and when Documentation is open to the public.

Obviously, if I knew I needed three, I would have written one more (actually I did, but it was rejected). And, of course, it's too late now to do anything. But did I just misread/overlook something, or was I just unlucky enough to not have the minimum requirements?

Comment: I didn't see anything written about that either.

Comment: Isn't documentation still on beta? You should be able to get that badge still  AFAIK. Also, I don't get what does it mean "substantive piece". I think that's not very clear... At least for me...

Comment: I don't understand how this badge works: 295 users got it, and all of them got it yesterday. Does it means Beta was just 1 day yesterday??

Comment: That badge was for the *private* beta. They set up a separate stack exchange site just for documentation. Last week they merged it with this one and made it public yesterday.

Comment: I see, so that badge is no more available... That's sad!